# How to loop file names into an array or run custom code on it

Tags: command-line, bash, files

This is a qna post (Do not need help, just wanted to help others).

Recently worked with some files and had difficulty in reading the files

```
 #version1 (error on files with spaces)
 arrFiles[0]=0
 folderLocation="/home/thenok/.local/share/recent"
 for i in $(find "$folderLocation" ! -name "*~" -type f); do
  arrFiles[0]=$[arrFiles[0]+1]   arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]="$i" 
  echo arrFiles at pos ${arrFiles[0]} found ${arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]} 
 done
```

found a (good) solution:

```
 #version2 works (ok but the global variable change bothered me)
 IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
 arrFiles[0]=0
 folderLocation="/home/thenok/.local/share/recent"
 for i in $(find "$folderLocation" ! -name "*~" -type f); do
  arrFiles[0]=$[arrFiles[0]+1]   arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]="$i" 
  echo arrFiles at pos ${arrFiles[0]} found ${arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]} 
 done
```

Because I did not want to alter the IFS global variable, i tried using the exec command in find, but variable modification was a dead end (no code for version 3, lost it)

After browsing a bit I found we can use read to pipe:

```
#version4 (horrible side effect of piping is that all variables altered between do and done do not last, maybe some people will like that)
arrFileNames[0]=0 
folderLocation="/home/thenok/.local/share/recent"
find "$folderLocation" ! -name "*~" -type f | while read i; do 
 arrFileNames[++arrFileNames[0]]=${i} ;
 echo arrFiles at pos ${arrFiles[0]} found ${arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]}
done
```

and managed to make it work

```
#version5 works perfectly 
folderLocation="/home/thenok/.local/share/recent"
arrFileNames[0]=0 && while read i; do arrFileNames[++arrFileNames[0]]=${i} ; 
 #insert custom code
 echo arrFiles at pos ${arrFiles[0]} found ${arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]} 
 #end custom code
done < <( find "$folderLocation" ! -name "*~" -type f)
```

Debugging:

```
find "$folderLocation" ! -name "*~" -type f
#will show all files that match search location, '-type f' files not folders, '! -name "*~"' avoids backup files (usually created by office or text editors as a backup in case writing to disk failed)
#to search for a specific file name add '-name "*.pdf"' for all pdf files 
#for folder path add '-path "*/torrent/*"'
#add ! to match opposite '! -path "*/torrent/*" ! -name "*.pdf"' folder name must not contain folder called torrent and must not be a pdf
#for only current folder add ' -maxdepth 1' as first argument ie 'find  "$folderLocation" -maxdepth 1  ! -name "*~" -type f'

#for more complex conditions you can use '\(' '\)' '!' '-or' '-and'
find  "$folderLocation" -maxdepth 1  \(\( ! -name "*~" -or -path "*/torrent/*" \) -and \( -name "*~" -and ! -path "*/torrent/*" \)\) -type f'
```

Comment: It's great that you are trying to help others ! We really welcome that ! Small suggestion though , split the post in to the actual question part and post the question down bellow. The site itself is Q&A, so it's better to adhere to the format

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure none of your filenames contains newlines, with bash you'd write:

```
mapfile -t arrFiles < <(find "$folderLocation" ! -name "*~" -type f)
```

A bash only way:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob extglob
arrFiles=( **/!(*~) )
```

But that will include directories. To filter them out you could

```
arrFiles=()
for f in **/!(*~); do
    [[ -f $f ]] && arrFiles+=("$f")
done
```

To examine an array:

```
declare -p arrFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope people find it useful, Q&A-style

Version 5 works the best, but also version 2 work just right.